# $\ g(\sqrt{a^3}) \cdot g(\frac{1}{{a}^3}) \ge 1$ or $\ g(\sqrt{a^3}) \cdot g(\frac{1}{\sqrt{{a}^3}}) \ge 1$?

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N} $ and $ x_0,x_1,.....,x_n $ so that $x_0 + x_1 + .... x_n =1 $, $ a\in\mathbb{R} $ , $a>0$  and $\ g(t)=x_0t^n+x_1t^{n-1}+.....+x_n ,$ for all t $\in\mathbb{R} $.
Is any of these inequalities true?

$\ g(\sqrt{a^3}) \cdot g(\frac{1}{{a}^3}) \ge 1$ or $\ g(\sqrt{a^3}) \cdot g(\frac{1}{\sqrt{{a}^3}}) \ge 1$

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

If all $x_i$ are non-negative, $t\ge 0$ then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies that $g(t)g(1/t)\ge g(t\cdot 1/t)^2=1$. If not all $x_i$ are non-negative there is a counterexample: put $g(t)=2-t$ and $a=4$. Then $ \sqrt{{a}^3}=8$, $g(\sqrt{a^3})<0$, but both $g(1/{a}^3)$ and $g(1/\sqrt{{a}^3})$ are positive.